# Will custom fonts in my notebook be carried over?

Tags: stylesheet, fonts

In my notebook, I have Open Sans (a free font) as a text font and Consolas (a paid font) as a code font. Those fonts are coded into the stylesheet of my notebook. My question is: if I send someone a copy of my notebook, will it be rendered in those fonts or will they become default Mathematica fonts (IIRC Arial and Courier--yuck!)?

Comment: To my knowledge fonts are not embedded in notebooks. Cannot test right now though, but using the standard fonts would be the safe alternative for sharing.

Comment: Thank you. I plan to share my notebook and that's what I was afraid of. I'm trying to use common fonts that still look nice, and I'm struggling to find a fixed-width font beside Courier that will render across operating systems.

Comment: I guess you will have to test how that works out. Perhaps someone with more know-how will be able to chime in.

Comment: If it would be possible to embed Consolas I wonder about its legality. My guess is the receiver would need to have these installed as well.

Comment: Here is a list of font substitution in MMA: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FontSubstitutions.html. I guess if a notebook had a font that's not in one's computer, MMA will attempt to substitute it with a different font found in this rule.

Comment: @seismatica, Any News on that Topic?